# Sharepoint 2010: Using Infopath form to set parameters of multiple excel web parts

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I'm trying to have a simple InfoPath form with 3 fields send values to set the parameters of 2 different Excel Web Access Web Parts, each of which have the same parameters.

The problem is that when I set the connections up to both web parts from the form, which I'm pretty sure I'm doing correctly (get values for multiple parameters from), only one of the web parts gets filtered correctly, and the other remains unchanged. I've tried only using a single connection to each of the excel web parts individually, and it works fine as long as there's only 1 connection.

I've also tried changing the parameter names of the excel workbooks so they aren't the same as each other, just in case the naming was an issue, but it didn't help.

When using a standard Choice Filter, I'm able to filter both excel web parts correctly like I'm trying to do with the InfoPath form.

Any ideas? Haven't had much luck finding any information about problems with InfoPath forms and connections to multiple web parts anywhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In reading the issue, both web parts reside on the same page.

Using SharePoint Designer, check the SP tag near the top which should read. ~~

this will tell you what webpart ids are connected. Sometimes and for some reason some connections get removed and it is easier to re-establish here (follow a webpart connection tag as a sample) to manually recreate instead of starting over in the UI.

Comment: looks you forgot the link!!